# My Update Query Retrieves Nulls Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access, ms-access-2007

I created an update query through access 2007, I simply wanted to update the empty rows to another columns in the table.

```
                    UPDATE DISTINCTROW (ChangeList INNER JOIN (Current_INFO INNER JOIN Master_Database ON     
                    Current_INFO.[HEADER ID] = Master_Database.[HEADER ID]) AND (Current_INFO.[HG ID] = Master_Database.[HG ID])) ON 
                    ChangeList.[ZIP/POSTALCODE] = Master_Database.[ZIP/POSTALCODE]) INNER JOIN ChangeRequest ON 
                    Master_Database.[ZIP/POSTALCODE] = ChangeRequest.[ZIP/POSTALCODE] SET ChangeList.[CHANGE TA TO] = [Master_Database]![TA]
                    WHERE (((UCase([ACTION]))='UPDATE'));
```

[image]

This however doesn't work, it just returns me null values however if i turn this query into a simple select where i call [Master_Database]![TA] it returns me  the values i require.

Can anyone assist me please.Thank you!

Comment: Is the query actually updating? You  could  test by replacing `[Master_Database]![TA]` with a simple value like `"Test"`. I suspect  that your joins are making the query a non-updatable recordset.

Comment: Also, try removing the bang "!" and use a dot "." instead.

Comment: I'm sort of surprised this query does anything at all. I don't think you'll be able to Update using Distinct Row and your joins are likely to prevent updating too. I recommend using a DAO loop instead.